# Cache performance, improving execution time

Tags: architecture, cpu

I have the following situation:

> A machine takes on average c cycles per instruction without
>   considering memory stalls,
>       and has a miss penalty p for all misses. Let i and d be respectively the instruction cache
>       miss rate and data cache miss rate for a program with n instructions and f memory references
>       per instruction. Assume that the hit time is not a factor in determining cache performance.

I have worked out that the number of cycles required to run the program with memory stalls taken into account is n(c + ip + fdp).

The next part says:

> If we want to improve the execution time of this pro- gram by a factor
>   of k, how much do
>       we need to reduce the number of cycles that each instruction takes?
>       Another way to improve the execution time is to reduce the cycle time of the machine.
>       If we want to improve the execution time by a factor of k, how much do we need to
>       improve the cycle time?

I have got n(c + ip + fdp) / k so I'm thinking that the answer must be 1/k for the first part, but that seems too obvious. And surely if the cycle time is t then n(c + ip + fdp) * t gives the overall execution time, so it must be 1/k again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, I don't believe you are allowed to change anything other than c to get the desired speed-up; your solution assumes you are speeding up the cache misses as well.

The second part has a similar issue: speeding up the cycle time would not necessarily reduce the cache penalty, so the value of p would GROW as you reduced the cycle time (to keep the time constant, you'd need more of these shorter cycles).

This assumes, as you seem to, that p is measured in terms of cycles.

Comment: So if I have n((c/m) + ip + fdp) * t =  T/k where k is the speedup T is the execution time, t is the cycle time and m is the speedup of the cycle time required to cause a speedup k overall, would I be correct in saying that the speedup required is c / (((T/k)/nt) - ip - fdp)?